# How to count correctly letters with diacritics in text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I want to find frequency of different letters in a text, and some of them use diacritics. As example the text uses both 'å' and 'ą̊ '(U+00E5 U+0328) and the frequency needs to be counted for separately.

How do I do that?

I've tried using Counter collection, open the file using utf8 format, split the text string using both `text.split()` and `list(text)`, but python still counts 'å' and 'ą̊ ' as same letter!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that unicode text (forget about utf-8, I am talking after decoding your data to proper Python 3 strings) uses more than one unicode code point for some characters:  'ą̊ ' for example has two marks, so while both "ą" and "å" can exist as a single character after proper normalization, a character that takes both marks have to use one of the "combining mark" characters in unicode.

That means that Python `Counter` alone won't be able to handle it, without at least an extra step. In Python code, the way to findout about these marker characters is by using `unicodedata.category` - and it is not that friendly, it just returns a [two-character identifier for the category.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)

So, I think one thing that can be done is pre-process your text into a list where each character and its markings are normalized, using some "pure Python" code. Then, Counter could do its job.

It could be something along:

```
import unicodedata
from collections import Counter

characters = []

text = ...

# Decompose all characters into plain letters + marking diacritics:
text = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", text)
for character in text:
    if unicodedata.category(character)[0] == "M": 
        # character is a composing mark, so agregate it with
        # previous character
        characters[-1] += character
    else:
        characters.append(character)

counting = Counter(characters)
```

(Note that the snippet above does not take into account a potential malformed text snippet, that would start with a marking character in position 0)

Comment: "character" should not be in quotes on the line that reads `if unicodedata.category("character")[0] == "M":` as it refers to a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I tested and it works great, even for letters with double markers:)

I had to check up `unicodedata.normalize` and `unicodedata.category` so here are links if others need them;
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the special characters with another character that can be represented by a single code point before counting. Just make sure the substitution characters will not appear in the corpus.

```
text.replace('ą̊', 'Ʒ').replace('Ą̊', 'ʒ')
```